# Can´t Launch Whatsapp in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I can´t launch whatsapp from Xamarin.Forms

Interface:

```
public interface IWhatsApp
{
    void OpenWhatsApp(StringBuilder whatsapp);
}
```

Android:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(IWhatsApp))]
namespace Proyecto
{

public class WhatsAppAndroid : IWhatsApp
{
    public void OpenWhatsApp(StringBuilder whatsapp)
    {
        Intent was = new Intent();
        was.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
        //was.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, whatsapp.ToString());
        was.SetType("text/plain");
        was.SetPackage("com.whatsapp");
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(was);
    }
   }
}
```

Calling interface from main():

```
DependencyService.Get<IWhatsApp>().OpenWhatsApp(whatsapp);
```

Error:

Unhandled Exception:
System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type .IWhatsapp

Comment: Isn't it easier to use the "whatsapp://" custom URL scheme? No dependency service needed

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Basically just do a `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("whatsapp://send?text=Your text"));` from shared code. Also see: https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Upgraded it to an answer for you, please accept if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to use custom URL scheme for Whatsapp. That way you do not need a dependency service.

Just do it like this from your shared code: `Device.OpenUri(new Uri("whatsapp://send?text=Your text"));`

More documentation on the different options you have can be found here:  https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/iphone/23559013